Manhwa with a long white-haired male lead who used to be a slave of the female lead, and later became a powerful magician and killed her family
This manhwa has a long white-haired male lead, his eyes were either purple or red, I forgot, but he used to be a slave for the main character (MC) and then, later on the story, he became a powerful magician and killed the MC's whole family, except the MC.
He kept her in the top of a magic tower and kept her there until the MC managed to escape herself, since she has this wind god on her side or something. Both the male lead and the MC got along, though; they don't hate each other and more like they understood each other.
There was this other universe where the male lead was so powerful that he could see the MC, even though she wasn't supposed to be visible because it was just her dream (I think).

I Failed To Throw The Villain Away


"Now, you’re the only one left, Mistress." I reincarnated as the daughter of a baron within a novel I read in my previous life. Thanks to that I knew that the boy my father brought as a slave would massacre the barony, I would meet a horrifying death, and the ending of this world. I worked hard in order to avoid that miserable fate, but everything was for naught. In the end, at the hands of the one who awoke as the grand mage my father and all the servants died. And now I’ll die too... is what I thought? "I wanted to keep you, Mistress." The villain of this world began to become obsessed with me. ... But there wasn’t anything like this in the original? Valletta who began to verge away from the original work became closer to the dark truth of this world. From the Imperial family who is involved in dirty affairs and the appearance of unknown monsters. She only wanted to live freely but in a situation where she needs to save the world first! Will Valletta be able to find the life she wants?.


Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you describe this and explain how it matches the question?  Some links might be useful too, but not as important as including a synopsis.
